# DaysBetween in Pig Giving Wrong Result For Month Of March

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, vertica

I am trying to convert a vertica query into Pig which basically find out the number of days between two dates.When i converted the code and tried using the DaysBetween function in PIG it is giving different output for month of March only.

**PIG Result:**

```
Y = FOREACH X GENERATE
(DaysBetween((datetime)ToDate('2015-04-01'),ToDate('2015-03-01')));
Output:- (30)
```

**Vertica Result:**

```
SELECT JULIAN_DAY('2015-04-01')-JULIAN_DAY('2015-03-01');
Output:- (31)
```

When i checked the same for other months of the year,I am not getting any errors.

**PIG Result:**

```
Y = FOREACH X GENERATE
(DaysBetween((datetime)ToDate('2015-03-04'),ToDate('2015-02-04')));
Output:- (28)
```

**Vertica Result:**

```
SELECT JULIAN_DAY('2015-03-04')-JULIAN_DAY('2015-02-04');
 Output :- 28
```

I am unable to find the reason for the difference.Need some advice  on how to solve the issue.

Comment: I have a feeling maybe there is a daylight savings time issue going on here.  In your first example, it cross the daylight savings boundary subtracting an hour (and perhaps removing 1 day going from 12am to 11pm the prior day).  Daylight savings was 03-08.  Can you test out that theory?  I don't have a Hadoop cluster nearby right now.

Answer (score 0):

Specifying timezone to UTC or GMT will help.

```
Y = FOREACH X GENERATE
(DaysBetween((datetime)ToDate('2015-04-01', 'yyyy-MM-dd', 'UTC'),ToDate('2015-03-01', 'yyyy-MM-dd', 'UTC')));
```